# requestPermissions() method is showing error warning in Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I used `requestPermissions()` method in fragment and its working fine without showing any error or warning but when i use the same code in Activity for same purpose its working fine but showing an error warning. The following code i used in both fragment and Activity

```
requestPermissions(new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, CAMERA}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Its showing like this 
[image: Showing warning image]

Code is running correctly but its showing like this only in Activity not in fragment, Why and how can i fix this ?.

Comment: Your minimum api level version is 21 but requestPermission method works from version level 23.

Comment: In activity you can use ActivityCompat.requestPermissions

Comment: its showing error in this part "(new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, CAMERA}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)"

Answer (score 1):

Problem : [Runtime Permission](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/runtime-permissions) is part of MarshMallow & Above. Your current min API is 21(Lollipop) which does not have runtime permission.

Solution: *Either you need to check whether current API is above Marshmallow or use [ActivityCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat)*

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
   requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Or

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: Its showing error in this part "(new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, CAMERA}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)" when i am using ActivityCompat.

I am confused because its working in fragment without error

Comment: Append `Manifest.permission` in front of your permission or import those packages statically. I have updated my answer; please check.

Answer (score 1):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` you have specified `android:minSdkVersion = "21"` but this API is only available on SDK versions 23 and up.

You have to check the android version first or your app will crash on android versions 5.0 (SDK 21) and 5.1 (SDK 22)

For cheking and supporting different android versions refer to https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms

Comment: You may be using `FragmentCompat` (Support library/androidx) which likely has these checks internally. Support library is bundled with your app so it is available all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Your minimum api level version is 21 but requestPermission method works from version level 23.

So, to use requestPermission() method you must handle the version code-

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
{
 requestPermission(............................)
}
```